# Custom row labels in PivotTable

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet full of customer data including a few single letter categorical variables.

For example: property type can be (I for investment, O for owner occupier, or R for renter).  Is it possible to replace the single letter with a descriptive title in the rows on a PivotTable?  I do not have the descriptive names anywhere in my spreadsheet and I would prefer not to add them.

Comment: Pivot tables sit on top of the raw data contained in your spreadsheet, so I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do this without adding the labels to all your data.

Comment: @teylyn A juice Excel question coming right at you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give nicknames to the fields that you are checking which populate the pivot table.

If you go the pivot table data and right click you can change the value field settings to give a custom name to a row/series but I do not know about individual data points.

path: pivot table data => right click => select Field Settings => edit custom name.

It does not look like it modifies the raw data (before pivot table).
It adds the name to the chart as well. So make sure your chart looks okay.
to my knowledge this is the best tool for you to mess around with.
Hopefully this answers your question.
coming from experimenting on excel 2013.